# Изменение рисунка при нажатии на клавиши клавиатуры

Tags: android, клавиатура

Как сделать, чтобы у меня отдельные клавиши сменяли рисунок при клике, как у Google клавиатуры?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В слушателе `onTouchListener` проверьте `event.getAction()` на равенство `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` данного `View` и меняйте `background`

Comment: Я наследуюсь от InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener и что-то не очень понимаю как все правильно сделать(

Comment: Я никогда не игрался с клавиатурой, но попробуйте найти метод вроде `onKeyPressed()` или что-то вроде того, затем в этом методе изменяйте `background`. А в методе `onKeyReleased()` меняйте `background` на дефолтный.

Comment: @Herrgott, у меня получилось менять цвет определенных клавиш с помощью onPress и onDraw, но смена фона происходит только при смене раскладки... А это не очень хорошо.